# My pre_save signal isn't applying my string generator

Tags: django

I wrote a simple string generator for my order_id field.
I tested the generator script in shell, and it works perfectly.
But when I run the server, and try to create an order in django admin, the order id field remains empty when I click save.
What am I doing wrong?

```
from datetime import date
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

from cartapp.models import Cart

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Waiting', null=True, blank=True)
    order_total = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def order_id_generator(instance):
    today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    last_order_raw = Order.objects.latest('order_id').date_created
    last_order_date = str(last_order_raw).split(' ')[0]
    if today != last_order_date:
        new_order_id = str(today + " 1")
    else:
        last_order = Order.objects.latest('order_id')
        extract = last_order.order_id.split(' ')[1]
        increment = int(extract) + 1
        new_order_id = today + " " + str(increment)
    return new_order_id

def pre_save_order_id(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.order_id:
        instance.order_id = order_id_generator(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_order_id, sender=Order)
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are passing `instance` to `order_id_generator` but doesn't use it there. You can avoid using signals and you can use your function as the model field `default`:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=order_id_generator)
```

and you doesn't need an arg `instance` in your function:

```
def order_id_generator():
    today = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    last_order_raw = Order.objects.latest('order_id').date_created
    last_order_date = str(last_order_raw).split(' ')[0]
    if today != last_order_date:
        new_order_id = str(today + " 1")
    else:
        last_order = Order.objects.latest('order_id')
        extract = last_order.order_id.split(' ')[1]
        increment = int(extract) + 1
        new_order_id = today + " " + str(increment)
    return new_order_id
```